# Creating a jQuery object with text containing a special character

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to allow the user to copy/paste either text or html into a field.  I need to test the pasted text to see if it has a certain class but of course if it's plain text, it won't.  So I am making an object out of the pasted text and here is where my issue is.

I am performing the following:

```
let $data = $(pasted);
if ($data.length > 0) {
    if ($data.hasClass('bob') {
        // process my html with bob
    }
}
else {
    // paste plain text
}
```

Things are working out okay except when I use a character such as **?**.

If I paste the plain text "Not Bob", it get's placed in my field just fine.
If I paste the plain text "Not Bob?", an exception is thrown. `Syntax error, unrecognized expresession Not Bob?`

Obviously jQuery is attempting to handle that question mark.  How can I either prevent this or work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the HTML of an element to the pasted text, then examine that HTML - pass it to `.html` instead of `$`.

```js
const pasted = prompt('foo');
const elm = $('<div />');
elm.html(pasted);
if (elm.children().hasClass('bob')) {
  console.log('processing bob');
} else {
  console.log('processing plaintext');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```